# Print first and every nth column using awk

Tags: linux, awk, command-line

I want to print the 1st column (`gene`) and all the `raw_counts` columns in a tab-seperated file.

I've tried:

```
BEGIN {FS = "\t"}
{for (i = 3; i <= NF; i += 1) printf ("%s%c", $i, i + 1 <= NF ? "\t" : "\n");}
```

but the output is the same as the input.

```
awk -f prog.awk < input.csv > output.csv
```

Input Data:

`head -3 input.txt`

```
Hybridization REF       TCGA-A3-3306-01A-01R-0864-07    TCGA-A3-3306-01A-01R-0864-07    TCGA-A3-3306-01A-01R-0864-07   TCGA-A3-3307-01A-01R-0864-07     TCGA-A3-3307-01A-01R-0864-07    TCGA-A3-3307-01A-01R-0864-07
gene    raw_counts      median_length_normalized        RPKM    raw_counts      median_length_normalized        RPKM  
?|100130426     1       0.122549019607843       0.0330807728010661      0       0       0
```

Desired output:

```
Hybridization REF       TCGA-A3-3306-01A-01R-0864-07      TCGA-A3-3307-01A-01R-0864-07       
gene    raw_counts    raw_counts       RPKM   
?|100130426     1       0
```

Comment: Don't just show a header, include some data in your sample input/output. Why are you starting your loop at field 3 when the first raw_counts is field 2? Why aren't you also printing $1 if you want the gene column printed?

Comment: the latest update the sample input and desired output, does not match ... how do lines #1 and #3 end up with 3 fields of output while line #2 has 4 fields of output (why is `RPKM` at the end of line #2)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple tweaks:

- start the loop counter at `2`
- increment the loop counter by `+3` on each pass

Modifying OP's code:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {printf "%s",$1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i+=3) printf "%s%s",OFS,$i; print ""}' input.csv    
gene    raw_counts      raw_counts      raw_counts      raw_counts      raw_counts
```

---

After multiple changes to the sample input and expected output, the latest:

```
$ cat input.csv
Hybridization REF       TCGA-A3-3306-01A-01R-0864-07    TCGA-A3-3306-01A-01R-0864-07    TCGA-A3-3306-01A-01R-0864-07    TCGA-A3-3307-01A-01R-0864-07    TCGA-A3-3307-01A-01R-0864-07      TCGA-A3-3307-01A-01R-0864-07
gene    raw_counts      median_length_normalized        RPKM    raw_counts      median_length_normalized        RPKM
?|100130426     1       0.122549019607843       0.0330807728010661      0       0       0
```

The above `awk` generates:

```
Hybridization REF       TCGA-A3-3306-01A-01R-0864-07    TCGA-A3-3307-01A-01R-0864-07
gene    raw_counts      raw_counts
?|100130426     1       0
```

Comment: The code seems to output it in space-separated format. How do I change it to tab-separated format?

Comment: the `FS=OFS="\t"` says to define the input and output field separators (FS, OFS) as tabs; if you pipe the output to `od` (eg, `awk ... | od -c`) you should see a `\t` between each column; NOTE: I had a typo in my original answer (had a `)` instead of a `}`) ... this has been fixed ... and, no, that typo would have created a syntax error instead of replacing `\t` with spaces

Comment: The first column in the input did not appear as the first column in the output file. The rows start with the other columns, and not column 1 of input

Comment: My raw input can be obtained with `wget http://gdac.broadinstitute.org/runs/stddata__2016_01_28/data/KIPAN/20160128/gdac.broadinstitute.org_KIPAN.Merge_rnaseq__illuminahiseq_rnaseq__unc_edu__Level_3__gene_expression__data.Level_3.2016012800.0.0.tar.gz`, if you need it

Comment: I've added sample `head -3 input.csv`.

Comment: the `od -c` output doesn't match your original inputs, nor the description that references `gene` and `raw_counts`; having said that, the `od -c` output shows the columns are tab-delimited, and if I modify my `input.csv` so that the first, tab-delimited column is `Hybridization REF` then this `awk` answer does print `Hybridization REF ...` as output; in your complete `od -c` output do you see a `\r` at the very end of the input line?

Comment: further debugging is going to require that we have a copy of the actual file, or at least the first couple lines; the most compact approach is probably going to be `head -2 input.csv | base64` ... we could at least reverse this (`base64 -d`) to create an exact copy of the file

Comment: `head -2 input.csv | base64` exceeds StackOverflow's output limit. `head -2 input.csv | base64 -d` results in &�سjبbase64: invalid input

Comment: the `base64 -d` is what we would run on our systems to reverse the output from `base64`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
FNR==1{
    header[1]
    for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i=="raw_counts") header[i]
}
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        if(i in header) {printf("%s%s", sep, $i); sep=OFS}
    print ""
}' file
```

First time though, it prints your headers and from then on only the values associated with those headers.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 1:** got the whole thing to work end to end ( the `http`**s** is essential) :

*—- I used `bsd-tar` instead of `gnu-tar`*

```
 curl -s -L -f -g '

   https://gdac.broadinstitute.org/runs/stddata__2016_01_28/
                                       data/KIPAN/20160128/
           gdac.broadinstitute.org_KIPAN.
            Merge_rnaseq__illuminahiseq_rnaseq__unc_edu__Level_3
             __gene_expression__data.Level_3.2016012800.0.0.tar.gz' | 

 tar -xvO -f- |

 mawk '{ print $1 '"$( jot -s '' -w ',$%d' - 2 14 3 )"' }' OFS='\t' | 

 gcat -n
```

> 

```
 1  8c6f0954749188f5266253fd418d6d9f    KIPAN.rnaseq__illuminahiseq_rnaseq__unc_edu__Level_3__gene_expression__data.data.txt                
 2  Hybridization   REF TCGA-A3-3306-01A-01R-0864-07    TCGA-A3-3307-01A-01R-0864-07    TCGA-A3-3308-01A-02R-1325-07    TCGA-A3-3311-01A-02R-1325-07
 3  gene    raw_counts  raw_counts  raw_counts  raw_counts  raw_counts
 4  ?|100130426 1   0   0   3   0
 5  ?|100133144 70  47  159 168 236

 6  ?|100134869 46  19  50  71  138
 7  ?|10357 135 138 245 325 266
 8  ?|10431 1715    1625    2743    3801    5171
 9  ?|136542    0   0   0   0   0
10  ?|155060    464 476 1874    771 740
  .
  .
 20531  ZYX|7791    4944    8779    19825   19639   12883
 20532  ZZEF1|23140 3233    3306    8731    9156    17034
 20533  ZZZ3|26009  3061    2405    4269    5967    6594
 20534  psiTPTE22|387590    379 377 675 669 1385
 20535  tAKR|389932 5   5   31  27  36
```

Don't waste time looping the columns — *use either `seq` or `jot` to dynamically generate static `awk` code on the fly :*

```
  gawk -be '{ print $1 '"$( jot -s '' -w ',$%d' - 2 14 3 )"' }'

  # gawk profile, created Fri Feb  3 13:08:10 2023

  # Rule(s)

 1  {
 1      print $1, $2, $5, $8, $11, $14
     }


gene raw_counts raw_counts raw_counts raw_counts raw_counts
```